# print call stack of makefile without add log line by line

Tags: makefile

Android build system is very big. I would like to find out the defined function call stack, just like C/C++ call backtrace, which let me know which file is calling current function.

e.g.

```
define copy-file-to-target-with-cp
@mkdir -p $(dir $@)
$(hide) rm -f $@
$(hide) cp -p "$<" "$@"
endef
```

I know it maybe work just add log at all code line which call this function, but it's tedious, any better solution?

Comment: There is nothing like that available.  Just to mention that it's probably a mistake to think of these things like "functions"; makefiles don't really support functions.  They are macros that are expanded.  There's nothing in GNU make that will show the "history" of an expansion as it happens.

Comment: To me its unclear whether you talk about `make` functions or some kind of recipe-"function"? If the former and not the latter, you could use or modify the `-gmtt-dbg-args` function which is the first function (internal though, and not documented) at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/master/gmtt.mk. It will print on stdout (I think you can use stderr if you exchange `info` with `warning`) the current function name followed by all parameters (up to param 6 but I think you get the idea how to extend). You would need to add a `$(-gmtt-dbg-args)` in each function in your makefile(s) tho.